# KerasRegressor Coefficient of Determination R^2 Score

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras, tensor

I'm building a small neural net in Keras meant for a regression task, and I want to use the same accuracy metric as the scikit-learn [RandomForestRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.score):

> The coefficient R^2 is defined as `(1 - u/v)`, where `u` is the regression sum of squares `((y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum()` and `v` is the residual sum of squares `((y_true - y_true.mean()) ** 2).sum()`.

It's a handy metric because it shows values up to 1.0 (similar to percent accuracy in classification). Is my usage of Keras backend correct for the accuracy metric I want?

```py
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam", metrics=[det_coeff])
    return model

# Is this computing the right thing?
def det_coeff(y_true, y_pred):
    u = K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred))
    v = K.sum(K.square(y_true - K.mean(y_true)))
    return K.ones_like(v) - (u / v)
```

This appears to work in that nothing errors and the metric is increasing towards 1 over time, but I want to be sure I implemented the metric correctly.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you can check [this post](https://jmlb.github.io/ml/2017/03/20/CoeffDetermination_CustomMetric4Keras/) out. I tested the following code and it works ok for your purpose.

```
from keras import backend as K

def coeff_determination(y_true, y_pred):
    SS_res =  K.sum(K.square( y_true-y_pred ))
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square( y_true - K.mean(y_true) ) )
    return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot + K.epsilon()) )
```

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow has [add-ons](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons) as a separate module named "tensorflow-addons" which you can install using `pip install tensorflow_addons`. It includes some common metrics such as R2-score. To use R2-score as an evaluation metric, you can simply import it, instantiate it and pass it as a metric:

```py
from tensorflow_addons.metrics import RSquare
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=[RSquare()])
```

Another option is to directly use `sklearn.metrics.r2_score`. However, because keras uses tensors and scikit-learn uses numpy arrays, you must set `run_eagerly=True` to avoid a NotImplementedError. It must be noted that this considerably slows down the code, so unless you have a small NN, it's probably better to use the other option.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=[r2_score], run_eagerly=True)
```